# Creating a project from an existing source does not work

Tags: android, eclipse

Someone has already worked on a project before me and he does not work anymore in our company ; I copied the whole directory where he created the project :

[image]

I use the Eclipse IDE which is provided by the ADT bundle under the eclipse folder ; I already launched the SDK Manager to install all necessary packages. Now I create an android project from this source , and selected the parent directory in the root directory field. The problem is that after clicking the OK button then there is no project created/imported ! So how to create a new project from this source ?

Comment: I believe this is already answered in another question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301759/importing-existing-android-project-into-eclipse

Comment: Use Export method from File menu and import in your directory and clean that project after importing it

Answer (score 1):

Use File -> Import in eclipse, and in the dialog, expand the `Android` directory, and then click `Existing Android code into workspace`. Click Browse and locate the root directory of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Include it as an Android Project.

Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace

Answer (score 1):

Just Import the android project by,

**Step 1** :  File -> Import -> Expand Android -> Select Existing Android Code into Workspace & Click Next.

[image]

**Step 2** : Now, browse your project & Click Finish to import the project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hope this trick may work for you.

create new project as usual and make sure that you old project name and  new project names are same and package names also same. after creating new project just exit the eclipse. And replace the main folders of new project with old project folders like src, drawable.

Now re-open the eclipse. refresh the project. and edit the manifest file to match old one.

All The Best.

Comment: the main folders have already same name ! I dont need to change ! So what to do ?

Comment: Just copy the source code of old project into new project